# Не выполняется код на определённой строке

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Всем привет. Не могу понять почему не выполняется код. После прохождения определённой строки остальная часть кода пропускается, и страница успешно загружается.

```
        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(resourselist);
        InfoWithPanel info = await db.Infos.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
//этот код не выполняется
            if (info == null)
            {
                var addedinfo = new InfoWithPanel() { Resourses = json, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now };
                infoWithPanelRepository.Create(addedinfo);
            }
            else
            {
                var updatedinfo = new InfoWithPanel() { id = info.id, Resourses = json, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now };
                infoWithPanelRepository.Update(updatedinfo);
            }
// этот код не выполняется
```

Код который не выполняется отмечен курсивом. Вот гифка отладки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скриншот всего метода. i.imgur.com/edu2PTL.png

Comment: Вам стоит почитать книги по языку. Вкратце - так устроен async/await.

Comment: Значит метод `async void` и вы его не ожидаете. Но вы же нам не покажете, что это за метод.

Comment: Вот скриншот всего метода. https://i.imgur.com/edu2PTL.png

Comment: Окей, и где вы вызываете этот метод `await GetInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отладчик почему-то пропускал момент условия где стояла точка останова.
Я поставил дополнительные точки, и теперь он показал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если образно, то это происходит из-за того, что собранные бинари не подкладываются в IIS Express.

Должно помочь:

1. ПКМ по проекту --> Очистить
2. ПКМ по проекту --> "Свойства" --> "Web" --> Кнопка "Создать виртуальную директорию"